# How to filter x2many?

Tags: odoo

Is it possible filter list of x2many records in form view?

For example:

1)Show only first 5 lines.

2)Show only records, that have fields according to some domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can defiantly do that but usually adding domain in o2m field is nor functionally useful. O2m is designed to the show related record and if you hide related record it may be not good idea.

Bests